# How to search keyword on Google using Python QwebView

Tags: python, pyqt4, qwebview

I want to search one by one keyword on Google using Python QWebView.My code is as follow in which only last keyword search and return that keyword result.

If any have idea about how to search multiple keyword on Google using Python Qt , Please share your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import time 
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebElement, QWebElementCollection



class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.web = QWebView()
        layout.addRow("Search",self.web)

        self.start = QPushButton("Start")
        self.start.setDefault(True)
        self.start.clicked.connect(lambda:self.search_keyword(self.start))

        layout.addRow(self.start)

    def search_keyword(self,b):
        for keyword in ["Python Tutorial","Android Tutorial","VB Tutorial"]:
            self.web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com?q="+keyword))
            self.web.show()
            print self.web.connect(self.web, QtCore.SIGNAL('loadFinished(bool)'), self._loadFinished)


    def _loadFinished(self,ok):

        frame = self.web.page().mainFrame()
        doc=frame.documentElement()
        button = doc.findFirst("input[type=submit]")
        button.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()")   
        self.web.loadFinished.connect(self.searchResults)

    def searchResults(self):
        results = self.web.page().currentFrame().documentElement().findAll('h3.r a').toList()
        for result in results:
            url=str(result.attribute('href'))
            link=url[url.index('q')+2:url.index('&')]
            print link
            break



def main():



    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    ex.setGeometry(300, 200, 470, 320)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```